# Spring MVC, how to pass a parameter to thymeleaf view when redirecting

Tags: spring-mvc, redirect, thymeleaf

I am using Spring MVC and thymeleaf in my web application.

In one of the scenario I have a controller which do a redirecting at end of its functionality. I need to pass a parameter (actually a success/fail alert message) to my front end. How can I implement this behavior.

I could know that model.addAttribute() cannot be implemented when there is a redirection.

Following is the controller code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteForm544(@RequestParam("id") final Long inForm544Id) {

    logger.info("Hit the /Form544/delete ");
    logger.info("Change Status Deleted of Form 544 ID : " + inForm544Id);

    JSONObject alertObj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        form544Service.setStatusAsDeleted(inForm544Id);

        alertObj.put("type", "success");
        alertObj.put("msg", "Successfully deleted Form 544 with ID Number " + inForm544Id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error occured " + e);

        alertObj.put("type", "fail");
        alertObj.put("msg", "Form 544 deletion failed. Due to " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return new ModelAndView("redirect: filter_view");
}
```

Following is the view(thymeleaf) code. [Note: I need to get the value to a javascript variable]

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var alertObj = ([[${alert}]]);
    /*]]>*/

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally referring to some articles, I could find a solution using `RedirectView` and `redirectAttributes.setFlashAttributes()`.

Following is the Controller(Spring MVC) function:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView deleteForm544(@RequestParam("id") final Long inForm544Id,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    logger.info("Hit the /Form544/delete ");
    logger.info("Change Status Deleted of Form 544 ID : " + inForm544Id);

    JSONObject alertObj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        form544Service.setStatusAsDeleted(inForm544Id);

        alertObj.put("type", "success");
        alertObj.put("msg", "Successfully deleted Form 544 with ID Number " + inForm544Id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error occured " + e);

        alertObj.put("type", "fail");
        alertObj.put("msg", "Form 544 deletion failed. Due to " + e.getMessage());
    }

    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    redirectView.setContextRelative(true);
    redirectView.setUrl("filter_view");
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alert", alertObj);

    return redirectView;
}
```

Following is the view (Thymeleaf) code. [NOTE: I am getting the alert response to a JavaScript variable]

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

     /*<![CDATA[*/
    var alertObj = ([[${alert}]]);
    /*]]>*/

</script>
```